# Oracle saving arabic numbers as "??"

Tags: c#, oracle10g, arabic, unicode-string, oledbdatareader

Working on Winform based app connecting Oracle via OleDbDatareader, when I save any data having arabic number, for instance: **اب۸۴۴**  it saves it as **اب???**

I am using varchar type. It is weird it save non numeric data as it is but entering digits in arabic keyboard messes with entire string.

I am using Oracle 10g XE

Comment: [related comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347563/connect-c-sharp-windows-form-application-to-oracle-db#comment21679096_15347563) (only part 2)

Comment: What is your database character set?  Are you using the Unicode version of Oracle XE?

Comment: @JustinCave How can I check it? Also I would like to tell that in production we will be using Oracle Standard Edition

Comment: @HighCore I don't know what kind of related code your are asking for, It is a simple select and isnert query, data type is Varchar2

Comment: What does `select value from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'` return?

Comment: it returns *AL32UTF8* on executing the query

Comment: @JustinCave any idea please?

Comment: If you `select dump(column_name) from table_name where some_condition`, that will show you the actual code points stored in the database.  Is the data being stored correctly (indicating the the problem is a display issue)?  Or is the data being stored incorrectly (indicating that the problem occurs while writing the data)?

Comment: It is not being store correctly either

Comment: did you find the solution @Volatil3 please write it here